# Sorting a HTML table on a column whose sortable value is not displayed. Any existing solutions?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, html-table, hidden

I know that there are many table sorters out there. For example, tablesorter, datatables, etc. But I did not find anything ready out there where I can sort the column on some internally associated value. Easy to explain example: Date and time is retrieved as a simply UNIX integer time but display is formatted using a formatting string that may not provide ascending or descending dates, if sorted on the ASCII displayed string. E.g. sort on a date displayed like 12/31/2011 will not provide temporal sorting. I know that there are options in sort sorters to  sort by date specifically but I am looking for a generic solution for datatypes that go beyond standard types such as date.

Any suggestions would be welcomed. I want to code in JQuery. I am looking more for an algorithmic approach rather than how to code. For example, where to maintain the hidden value? Data-xxx attribute for example in the "td" of the column and have that same attribute set to a boolean Y or N in the "th" of that column to indicate sort type on display or data value?

If existing solutions exist, please mention them. I did not find any but then again I may have missed one.

Comment: If you use `data-date="2012-11-30"` you can sort that in numerical order. But have you considered using MySQL to sort your data?

Comment: Sorting in MySQL is different than browser sorting. When sorting in Mysql, you get, let us say 200 records sorted on field f1. You display the first 15 records in the page (data pagination). Now the user wants to sort these 15 records in the browser on field f3. This is the problem I am referring to. See @Martinez's comments. You will understand the problem from the proposed solution. Thanks anyway as your suggestion is a logical one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Jquery Datatables (http://datatables.net/). You can extend the pluggin to add new "data format".

Example:

I'm from Spain and the date is represented by the format: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

If I use the sorter that the pluggin use to order dates, the date is ordered like a string (the pluggin suposes the data format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

You have to do a function to return an integer that is the "weight" of the date, '20/10/2013' has less weight than '15/11/2013' so 20/10/2013 is lesser than 15/11/2013.

For the format of dd/mm/yyyy the function to calculate the weight is: (you can change to mm/dd/yyyy changing the indexes of frDateParts)

```
function dateHeight(dateStr){
        if (trim(dateStr) != '') {
                var frDate = trim(dateStr).split(' ');
                var frTime = frDate[1].split(':');
                var frDateParts = frDate[0].split('/');
                var day = frDateParts[0] * 60 * 24; /*<--- in mm/dd/yyyy is frDateParts[1]*/
                var month = frDateParts[1] * 60 * 24 * 31; /*<--- in mm/dd/yyyy is frDateParts[0]*/
                var year = frDateParts[2] * 60 * 24 * 366;
                var hour = frTime[0] * 60;
                var minutes = frTime[1];
                var x = day+month+year+hour+minutes;
        } else {
                var x = 99999999999999999; 
        }
        return x;
}
```

And the extension of the pluggin:

```
/* NOTE: the new format is called "date-euro" (why not? xD) so:
you have to do the "date-euro-asc" for ascendent order and the "date-euro-desc"
 for descendent order. the return of the function has to be 
-1 (lesser), 0 (equal) or 1 (greater)*/

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['date-euro-asc'] = function(a, b) {
        var x = dateHeight(a);
        var y = dateHeight(b);
        var z = ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        return z;
};

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['date-euro-desc'] = function(a, b) {
        var x = dateHeight(a);
        var y = dateHeight(b);
        var z = ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
        return z;
};
```

and when you define the table with the datetables plugin to that column:

```
 { "sType": "date-euro"},
```

Example (table with 5 columns (Int, string , Date,string, string):

```
  "aoColumns": [
         { "sType": 'numeric' },
           null,
           { "sType": "date-euro"},
           null,
           null 
     ],
```

Comment: I looked at Datatables but it is a bit on the heavy side for my simple requirements. I do a lot of the paging and AJAX on my own and there is a lot of custom heavy-stuff that I have to do. Tablesorter fitted nicely but does not have the option (or I will see again if it does) to have a hook for giving weight to a cell value. Your answer is very useful. If nothing else comes in with a better solution, I will accept your answer. I have upvoted it as it is certainly useful.

Comment: I haven't use tablesorter, but with tablesorter you can specify the format of the date: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html maybe some of the formats can help you.

Comment: I want a generic solution not specific to date though thats an example I used. One way would be to prepend the displayed-data with some invisible "weight" string which is ascii sortable but have its display set to none in display. I will have to play around with it to see how the sort works with the inner display:none weight HTML tags in place inside the td tag. Perhaps you can use this approach too in the example you have given. I have not tried this approach at all... Just thought of it. Will give it a try and see now.

Comment: Tablesorter has a simple parser method that resolves this issue for me. Missed out on it earlier. Tablesorter is lightweight compared to Datatables. I will give datatables a more closer look.

Answer (score 0):

yes solutions is exists. You have to simple jquery table-sorter in your html. It will also usefull at development time.
You can sort out all fields or one field easily.

[jQuery Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. See @Pablo Martinez answer to understand the details. He got the question right for sure.